# Doesnt price compare after add merchant column

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

My scraper bot working normally till I add merchant column in database. Scraper.py file scraping success merchant and recorded in database correctly but compare bot not compare after add merchant column

[image]

My original code:(compare success)

```
# The max_date a product can have in order to be considered "old"
        limit = datetime.datetime.strptime(products[-1][1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") + \
            datetime.timedelta(minutes=OLDER_PRODUCTS_RANGE)

        # Separate "old" from "new" products
        for i, product in enumerate(products[::-1]):
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                product[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

            index = len(products) - i - 1
            if date > limit:
                old_products = products[index+1:]
                new_products = products[:index+1]
                break

        # If we have only one or even none of the lists, return
        if len(new_products) == 0 or len(old_products) == 0:
            c.close()
            self.save_db(db)

            return True

        older_product = min(old_products, key=lambda x: x[5])
        current_product = min(new_products, key=lambda x: x[5])

        first_price = older_product[5]
        current_price = current_product[5]
        current_date = current_product[1]

        url = current_product[6]

        price_difference = first_price - current_price
        percentage = price_difference / first_price
        percentage_str = str("%.2f" % (percentage * 100))

        # If the drop in the price was greater then the expected percentage, warn the user
        if percentage >= self.percentage:
            rowid = current_product[0]
            product_name = current_product[4]
            product_id = current_product[3]

            print(
                f"[Bot] [{current_date}] Price of \"{product_name}\" is {percentage_str}% off")

            message = product_name + "\n\n" + \
                str(first_price) + " TL >>>> " + \
                str(current_price) + f" TL - {percentage_str}%" + "\n\n" + \
                MAIN_URL + url + "\n\n" + \
                MAIN_URL + "ara?q=" + product_id

            context.bot.send_message(
                chat_id=CHANNEL_ID,
                text=message
            )

            c.execute(
                "INSERT INTO deleted SELECT rowid FROM products WHERE product_id = %s AND rowid != %s;",
                (product_id, rowid)
            )

        c.close()
        self.save_db(db)

        return True
```

My edited Code: (doesnt price compare)

```
# The max_date a product can have in order to be considered "old"
        limit = datetime.datetime.strptime(products[-1][1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") + \
            datetime.timedelta(minutes=OLDER_PRODUCTS_RANGE)

        # Separate "old" from "new" products
        for i, product in enumerate(products[::-1]):
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                product[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

            index = len(products) - i - 1
            if date > limit:
                old_products = products[index+1:]
                new_products = products[:index+1]
                break

        # If we have only one or even none of the lists, return
        if len(new_products) == 0 or len(old_products) == 0:
            c.close()
            self.save_db(db)

            return True

        older_product = min(old_products, key=lambda x: x[5])
        current_product = min(new_products, key=lambda x: x[5])

        first_price = older_product[5]
        current_price = current_product[5]
        current_date = current_product[1]
        
        url = current_product[6]

        merchant = current_product[7]

        price_difference = first_price - current_price
        percentage = price_difference / first_price
        percentage_str = str("%.2f" % (percentage * 100))

        # If the drop in the price was greater then the expected percentage, warn the user
        if percentage >= self.percentage:
            rowid = current_product[0]
            product_name = current_product[4]
            product_id = current_product[3]
            

            print(
                f"[Bot] [{current_date}] Price of \"{product_name}\" is {percentage_str}% off")

            message = product_name + "\n\n" + \
                + "Satici Adi:" + merchant + "\n\n" + \
                str(first_price) + " TL >>>> " + \
                str(current_price) + f" TL - {percentage_str}%" + "\n\n" + \
                MAIN_URL + url + "?magaza=" + merchant + "\n\n" + \
                MAIN_URL + "ara?q=" + product_id

            context.bot.send_message(
                chat_id=CHANNEL_ID,
                text=message
            )

            c.execute(
                "INSERT INTO deleted SELECT rowid FROM products WHERE product_id = %s AND rowid != %s;",
                (product_id, rowid)
            )

        c.close()
        self.save_db(db)

        return True
```

I use python with beautifulsoup4

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is you have extra `+` symbol here:

```
message = product_name + "\n\n" + \
              + "Satici Adi:" + merchant + "\n\n" + \
              str(first_price) + " TL >>>> " + \
              str(current_price) + f" TL - {percentage_str}%" + "\n\n" + \
              MAIN_URL + url + "?magaza=" + merchant + "\n\n" + \
              MAIN_URL + "ara?q=" + product_id
```

You should replace it by:

```
message = product_name + "\n\n" + \
              "Satici Adi:" + merchant + "\n\n" + \
              str(first_price) + " TL >>>> " + \
              str(current_price) + f" TL - {percentage_str}%" + "\n\n" + \
              MAIN_URL + url + "?magaza=" + merchant + "\n\n" + \
              MAIN_URL + "ara?q=" + product_id
```

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: So what error do you have? Could you specify output or explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: I dont have any error, just I use test price for compare but bot doesnt any compare. Not any error

Comment: You have to create a minimal, reproducible example because it is impossible to run your code and determine the problem. You can learn more about how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)